# Division by Zero error Occurred SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Function, where i'm receiving a "Division by Zero Error Occurred" message.  Here is my function:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Commission
    (
    @startdate DateTime,
    @enddate Datetime,
    @storenumber int,
    @tier1 int,
    @tier2 int,
    @tier1amount int,
    @tier2amount int

    )
RETURNS Table
AS

    RETURN


SELECT     A.Name, A.Total_Customers1, A.Amount, CASE WHEN B.Service1_Only_Customers1 IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE B.Service1_Only_Customers1 END AS Service1_Only_Customers1, 
                      CASE WHEN B.Service1_Only_Amount IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE CAST(CAST(B.Service1_Only_Amount AS Float) AS decimal(10, 2)) END AS Service1_Only_Amount, 
                      A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0) AS Payable_Customers1, A.Amount - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0) 
                      AS Payable_Amount, CAST((A.Amount - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) 
                      AS Decimal(10, 2)) AS Payable_Average, CASE WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                      / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1' WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) 
                      - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) < @Tier1 THEN '0' WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) 
                      - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) >= @Tier2 THEN '2' END AS PayoutTier, 
                      CASE WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0)) / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND 
                      @Tier2 THEN ((CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) * @Tier1Amount) / 100 WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) 
                      - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) 
                      < @Tier1 THEN '0' WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                      / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) >= @Tier2 THEN ((CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                      * @Tier2Amount) / 100 END AS PayoutAmount, ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0) AS Service2_Sales
FROM         (SELECT     COUNT(Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number) AS Total_Customers1, SUM(Invoice_Tb.Net_Sales) AS Amount, 
                                              Employee_Tb.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb.Last_Name AS Name
                       FROM          User_Tb RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                                              Invoice_Tb LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              Invoice_User_Role_Tb ON Invoice_Tb.Store_Number = Invoice_User_Role_Tb.Store_Number AND 
                                              Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Number = Invoice_User_Role_Tb.Invoice_Number AND Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date = Invoice_User_Role_Tb.Invoice_Date ON 
                                              User_Tb.User_Name = Invoice_User_Role_Tb.User_Name LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                              Employee_Tb ON User_Tb.User_Id = Employee_Tb.User_Id
                       WHERE      (Invoice_User_Role_Tb.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND 
                                              (Invoice_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate)
                       GROUP BY Employee_Tb.First_Name, Employee_Tb.Last_Name) AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     SUM(Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Extended_Price) AS Service2_Sales, Employee_Tb_2.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb_2.Last_Name AS Name
                            FROM          Invoice_Detail_Tb AS Invoice_Detail_Tb_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                   Employee_Tb AS Employee_Tb_2 INNER JOIN
                                                   User_Tb AS User_Tb_2 ON Employee_Tb_2.User_Id = User_Tb_2.User_Id INNER JOIN
                                                   Invoice_User_Role_Tb AS Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2 ON User_Tb_2.User_Name = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Name ON 
                                                   Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Number = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.Invoice_Number
                            WHERE      (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRK') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRR') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRA') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRD') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRRI') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRP') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'BRS') OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Store_Number = @storenumber) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb_1.Category_Code LIKE 'LER')
                            GROUP BY Invoice_User_Role_Tb_2.User_Name, Employee_Tb_2.First_Name, Employee_Tb_2.Last_Name) AS C ON A.Name = C.Name LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     Employee_Tb_1.First_Name + ' ' + Employee_Tb_1.Last_Name AS Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number) 
                                                   AS Service1_Only_Customers1, SUM(Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales) AS Service1_Only_Amount
                            FROM          User_Tb AS User_Tb_1 INNER JOIN
                                                   Employee_Tb AS Employee_Tb_1 ON User_Tb_1.User_Id = Employee_Tb_1.User_Id INNER JOIN
                                                   Invoice_Detail_Tb INNER JOIN
                                                   Invoice_Tb AS Invoice_Tb_1 ON Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = Invoice_Tb_1.Store_Number AND 
                                                   Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Number = Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Number AND Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date = Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Date INNER JOIN
                                                   Invoice_User_Role_Tb AS Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1 ON Invoice_Tb_1.Store_Number = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.Store_Number AND 
                                                   Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Number = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.Invoice_Number AND Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Date = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.Invoice_Date ON 
                                                   User_Tb_1.User_Name = Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Name
                            WHERE      (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv0') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 21) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv1') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 10) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv2') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 15) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv3') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 26) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv4') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 6) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber) OR
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Detail_Code = 'serv5') AND (Invoice_User_Role_Tb_1.User_Role = 'Advisor') AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date >= @startdate) AND (Invoice_Tb_1.Invoice_Net_Sales <= 11) AND (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Invoice_Date <= @enddate) AND 
                                                   (Invoice_Detail_Tb.Store_Number = @storenumber)
                            GROUP BY Employee_Tb_1.First_Name, Employee_Tb_1.Last_Name) AS B ON A.Name = B.Name
```

I assume that this is an error where I start dividing to find a few different columns.  Most of the select statements are the same with the exception of what the case ends up being.  So i'm guessing in this area is where i'm having the problem:

```
CASE WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                          / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1'
```

I've tried adjusting the code to:

```
CASE WHEN Coalesce((CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                          / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) ,0)BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1'
```

And I've also tried:

```
CASE WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                          / (A.Total_Customers1 - NULLIF(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1'
```

My last attempt was:

```
CASE WHEN Coalesce((CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                          / (A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)),0) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1'
```

Can anyone provide some insight.  I have no idea what's coming up as '0' or Null at this point throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Division by Zero error` will occur when there is a division in query happening like this.

```
select 1/0
```

Use [**`NULLIF()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177562.aspx) function to avoid `divide by zero exeption`

change all your statements with `division` to something like this.

```
CASE WHEN (CAST(A.Amount AS float) - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Amount, 0) - ISNULL(C.Service2_Sales, 0)) 
                          / Nullif((A.Total_Customers1 - ISNULL(B.Service1_Only_Customers1, 0)) BETWEEN @Tier1 AND @Tier2 THEN '1',0)
```

Here `Nullif` will make the `denominator` as `null` when it is `zero`.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I didn't think to use the NULLIF around the entire denominator.  Thanks!